# psycopg2 cursor.copy_expert() BadCopyFileFormat: extra data after last expected column when writing WKB data

Tags: python, postgis, string, well-known-binary, binary

I am trying to write a [WKB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) representation (i.e. a binary string) of a [Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) Polygon into a [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/)/[PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) database using [psycopg2](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/) [cursor.copy_expert()](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert) for a bulk insert.

I narrowed down the issue to the following:

```
import psycopg2
from io import StringIO
from shapely import wkb
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

conn = psycopg.connect(**db_params)
curs = conn.cursor()

# creation of the tmp_table:
curs.execute(f"""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_table (
        id INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
        geom_field geometry(PolygonZ, 4326)
    );""")
conn.commit()

shape = np.array([
    [1.60, 1.11, 1.12],
    [1.63, 1.10, 1.16],
    [1.64, 1.14, 1.09]])

polygon_wkb = Polygon(shape).wkb

f = StringIO()
f.write(f"{polygon_wkb}\n")
f.seek(0)

curs.copy_expert(f"COPY tmp_table (geom_field) FROM STDIN WITH CSV DELIMITER ',';", f)
conn.commit()
```

=>

```
InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type integer: "b'\x01\x03\x00\x00\x80\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x9a\x99\x99\x99\x99\x99\xf9?\xc3\xf5(\\\x8f\xc2\xf1?\xecQ\xb8\x1e\x85\xeb\xf1?\x14\xaeG\xe1z\x14\xfa?\x9a\x99\x99\x99\x99\x99\xf1?\x8f\xc2\xf5(\\\x8f\xf2?=\n\xd7\xa3p=\xfa?=\n\xd7\xa3p=\xf2?q=\n\xd7\xa3p\xf1?\x9a\x99\x99\x99\x99\x99\xf9?\xc3\xf5(\\\x8f\xc2\xf1?\xecQ\xb8\x1e\x85\xeb\xf1?'"
CONTEXT:  COPY tmp_table, line 1, column id: "b'\x01\x03\x00\x00\x80\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x9a\x99\x99\x99\x99\x99\xf9?\xc3\xf5(\\\x8f\x..."
```

So I figured out from this error that I have to replaced `f.write(f"{polygon_wkb}\n")` by `f.write(f"1,{polygon_wkb}\n")` but then I face this strange error:

=>

```
BadCopyFileFormat: extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY tmp_table, line 1: "1,b'\x01\x03\x00\x00\x80\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x9a\x99\x99\x99\x99\x99\xf9?\xc3\xf5(\\\x8f..."
```

I cannot see what's wrong here, my table has only two fields:

- an `id` as primary key
- and a `geometry(PolygonZ)` for storing the WKB geometry.

I've got the same error if I dump the geometry to a WKT representation.

Last but not least, the same error occurs when leaving the `id` out of the query (because it's an `identity` field, hence it can be left to PostgreSQL to manage it) by specifying only the geometry field `geom_field`:

```
(...)
f.write(f"{polygon_wkb}\n")
(...)
curs.copy_expert(f"COPY tmp_table (geom_field) FROM STDIN WITH CSV DELIMITER ',';", f)
```

=>

```
BadCopyFileFormat: extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY tmp_table, line 1: "b'\x01\x03\x00\x00\x80\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x9a\x99\x99\x99\x99\x99\xf9?\xc3\xf5(\\\x8f\x..."
```

The WKB string is as follow when I print it in the console:

```
print(polygon_wkb)
b'\x01\x03\x00\x00\x80\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x9a\x99\x99\x99\x99\x99\xf9?\xc3\xf5(\\\x8f\xc2\xf1?\xecQ\xb8\x1e\x85\xeb\xf1?\x14\xaeG\xe1z\x14\xfa?\x9a\x99\x99\x99\x99\x99\xf1?\x8f\xc2\xf5(\\\x8f\xf2?=\n\xd7\xa3p=\xfa?=\n\xd7\xa3p=\xf2?q=\n\xd7\xa3p\xf1?\x9a\x99\x99\x99\x99\x99\xf9?\xc3\xf5(\\\x8f\xc2\xf1?\xecQ\xb8\x1e\x85\xeb\xf1?'
```

it seems to contain `\n` sequences. Is it possible that this is causing some trouble with the new line interpreter?

How could I fix that?

**Info:**

Python: 3.10.4 (main, Apr  2 2022, 09:04:19) [GCC 11.2.0]

psycopg2: '2.9.3 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)'

shapely: '1.8.1.post1'

PG:14 / PostGIS:3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use `.wkb_hex` in order to have a plain string (not a binary one, which would have been OK though for a usage by [`ST_GeomFromWKB()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromWKB.html)):

```
import psycopg2
from io import StringIO
from shapely import wkb
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

conn = psycopg.connect(**db_params)
curs = conn.cursor()

# creation of the tmp_table:
curs.execute(f"""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_table (
        id INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
        geom_field geometry(PolygonZ, 4326)
    );""")
conn.commit()

shape = np.array([
    [1.60, 1.11, 1.12],
    [1.63, 1.10, 1.16],
    [1.64, 1.14, 1.09]])

polygon_wkb = Polygon(shape).wkb_hex # <- here, use .wkb_hex instead of just .wkb

f = StringIO()
f.write(f"{polygon_wkb}\n")
f.seek(0)

curs.copy_expert(f"COPY tmp_table (geom_field) FROM STDIN WITH CSV DELIMITER ',';", f)
conn.commit()
```

Not very well documented, but here one can see it's a standard string:  https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html

[image: wkb_hex from shapely doc]